# Distributing In-House Business IOS Apps

Tags: ios, distribution

I'm running into a confusing part of IOS App distribution.
So I need a simple breakdown of what my restrictions are, concerning distributing my App to just my workers, co-workers, or anything considered "in-house". (which is another way of stating I don't want the app on the app store)

My situation is I develop for several companies, and all their employees (and some clients) will need my App to view reports.  And I don't want to publish the App, just distribute it to people as they need it, which is random.

In my Apple Developer account I see 2 options for In-House Distribution:

1. Custom B2B Apps
2. Ad Hoc Distribution

I have a few hundred devices to install my App.
I'm not sure which is best for my scenario.  Ad Hoc appears to have a 100 device limitation, but maybe that's for beta-testing, and not production release.
And I'm still trying to grasp what the B2B App program does.

Then I see some companies that allow for Beta-Testing, without the need for iTunes to get involved.

-TestFlightApp.com
-AppCentral.com
-HockeyApp

Seems cool these businesses allow me to alert people of any app updates, or invite people to download an app.  (seems appealing, since users need simplicity for downloading apps)

Is there a downside to using one of those services?  Does Apple have an issue with this 3rd-party thingy?

I'm very open to suggestions and insight. I'm new at this game.

Comment: My impression of TestFlightApp was that it's great, provided there are no trade secrets in the app.

Comment: TestFlight is cool but you'll need an enterprise license to do more than 100 devices. However, be clear that apple only allows use of ad-hoc for employees, contrators, etc. I think you might fall into that boat but I would check to make sure there is no legal implications.

Comment: True, I got the impression ad-hoc was meant for employees and contractors and the like.  Which is perfect for my scenario. What you're saying is ad-hoc won't allow more than 100?  If that's the case, then it won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an [enterprise license](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). It allows you to distribute to a white-list of in house devices. 
Compare [licenses](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/) here

Comment: It seems I do want the enterprise licence.  I didn't find a limit to devices, so if that's the case, then I'll have to go with it.

Comment: FYI the ent lic covers only your company. If deploying to another company you will want to look at the B2B portion of the normal developer license.