# iPhone installation of a Non AppStore app

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing a test suit for iOS devices (not a consumer product), The app should run on a selected set of devices that are used for testing.

The App incorporate code that will not go through AppStore verification, eg. It is sending system-wide Key-Stroke events.

Using a developer account an app can be installed on a selected set of devices used for testing.

The App should be part of a Turn-Key solution, and thus, cannot require a dev account, while still, should be installable on an iOS device.

Having the above use-case in mind, is there any way of installing an App on a **non JailBroken** device w/o having a developer account ? ( Same as w/ Android )

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app?rq=1

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318143/distributing-in-house-business-ios-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code ever goes through App Store verification. Apps get verified. Code does not. No one at Apple can see your code even if they wanted to.

You can use Apple's enterprise stuff to do this. You can either distribute through the App Store (to a specific set of devices) or host it yourself.

If you look at the Apple enterprise stuff you can find more details.

Here you go... https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/